# Mathematical equivalent of Matlab special case element-wise multiplication similar to Schur-product

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matlab

I'm searching for the mathematical name and notation of a special case of the element-wise multiplication `.*` in Matlab shown in the following picture:

[Desired Operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tldom.png)

I'm aware that this would be called Hadamard- or Schur-product for the case of equal dimensions but how can this operation be denoted for cases like the given one?

Thanks.

Comment: are you searching for the MATLAB operation that does the desired operation in the link you shared ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi The Matlab Operation '.*' does exactly the operation in the given example. 
'[1, 2; 3, 4].*[1;2]' wil result in '[1, 2; 6, 8]'
I was just curious if there was a predefined mathematical operator for this operation but appearently there isn't :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen a standard notation for this, but you could easily define one. Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to M_{2\times 2}$ send $(\alpha, \beta)$ to the diagonal matrix with those entries. Then your operation is
$$A \,.^*\, v = f(v)A.$$

Comment: I agree, there is no standard name, but I guess if you talk about Hadamard/Schur, people would understand?!